# How to use performSelector for object value assignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, performselector

I want to use a new LocationManager property in iOS 9, I would write:

```
if ([_manager respondsToSelector:@selector(allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates)]){
        _manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
}
```

But how to use the performSelector here, so that the line compiles in both XCode 6 and 7, since above would give compile error on XCode 6 as `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` is not available there, one option could have been to use the default object setter method

```
[_manager performSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates) withObject:@{1}];
```

but I see no selector in intellisense for :

> setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates

so how to write such a statement using performSelector?

Comment: You cannot use `performSelector:withObject:` with this method because its parameter is not a pointer to object type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are missing ":"

```
[_manager performSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:) withObject:@{1}];
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector is called `setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:` (note the colon), so this should work:

```
if ([_manager respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)]){
    [_manager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
}
```